# Наибольшая сумма расположенных по возрастанию элементов отличающихся друг от друга разрядом единиц

Tags: c#, linq

Помогите пожалуйста написать linq, который найдет в массиве наибольшую сумму элементов отличающихся друг от друга разрядом единиц и расположенных по возрастанию.

Мой код:

```
int[] mass = { -12, 56, 23, 23, -67, 45, -54, 13, 37 };
int summ = 0;
int[] ArrayOfSumms = new int[0];
for (int i = 0; i < mass.Length; i++)
{
    if (i < mass.Length - 1 && mass[i] < mass[i + 1] && mass[i] % 10 != mass[i+1] % 10)
    {
        summ += mass[i];
    }
    else
    {
        summ += mass[i];
        if (i == mass.Length - 2 && mass[i] < mass[i + 1] && mass[i] % 10 != mass[i + 1] % 10) summ += mass[i + 1];
        Array.Resize(ref ArrayOfSumms, ArrayOfSumms.Length + 1);
        ArrayOfSumms[ArrayOfSumms.Length - 1] = summ;
        summ = 0;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(ArrayOfSumms.Max());
```

Правильный ответ 44.

Comment: у тебя есть два предыдущих вопроса с примером linq. В чем принципиальное отличие от текущего вопроса?

Comment: @Grundy Эта как по мне гораздо сложнее предыдущих двух, у меня ничего толкового не вышло.

Comment: зачем обязательно linq? приведи пример входных данных и выходных

Comment: прежде чем задать вопрос, попробуйте самостоятельно разобраться в нем, а потом уже приходит в интернет за помощью и примером, что не получилось...

Comment: @Grundy Linq - потому что хочу научиться с ним работать, входные данные int[] a = { -12, 56, 23, 23, -67, 45, -54, 13, 37 }; выходные: 50

Comment: добавь пример непосредственно в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: @Grundy занятно что можно скопировать ссылку на редактирование вопроса и она отработает =)

Comment: Мне кажется что Linq для этой ситуации не совсем подходит. Как по мне, он больше для простых операций типа фильтра, преобразования и т.д, чтобы меньше думать и запись короче была. И да, если вы хотите его *выучить*, сначала сами попытайтесь решить задачу, или потренируйтесь на более простых.

Comment: Если вы хотите научиться, то наверное не стоит придумывать себе сразу сложные задачи. Вы вот например, пробовали придумать и решить более простую задачу - выбрать из IEnumerable<int> IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> где элементы расположены по возрастанию. Если решали - то покажите, как вы разделили текущую задачу на набор более простых, которые вы решали ранее и в чём сложность по сравнению с предыдущими.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делается это в несколько этапов.

Я буду демонстрировать на примере последовательности:

```
var source = new[] { 100, 100, 102, 104, 103, 107, 2200, 2100, 2200, 2202, 2204, 2203, 2205 };
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во-первых, получим последовательность из безымянных элементов, когда каждый элемент пронумерован:

```
source.Select((x,y) => new {From = x, Num = y })
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но более полезно, когда у нас для каждого элемента получена последовательность из этих же элементов (начиная с текущего) до конца исходной:

```
source.Select((x,y) => new {From = x, Num = y, Rest = source.Skip(y) });
```

Во-вторых, нам бы рассчитывая Rest остановиться сразу как только текущий элемент стал меньше предыдущего. Для этого мы будем использовать функцию TakeWhile(условие), но сначала нам нужно научиться рассчитывать это условие, что текущий элемент больше/меньше предыдущего.

Давайте снова на примере исходной последовательности:

```
source.Zip(source.Skip(1), (x, y) => y > x);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У нас есть сама последовательность и она же сдвинутая на один элемент, функцией Zip мы сшиваем данные воедино.

Теперь подошьём две эти части воедино (ммм, я похоже не самым оптимальным путём пошёл, можно было быстрее придти к желаемому):

```
source.Select((x, y) => new { 
    From = x, 
    Num = y,
    Rest = source.Skip(y).Take(source.Skip(y).Zip(source.Skip(y).Skip(1), (a, b) => b > a).TakeWhile(e => e == true).Count()),
}).Dump();
```

Получаем уже достаточно интересный результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше уже идут достаточно базовые linq-операции: найти для каждой IEnumerable сумму элементов, выбрать максимальную сумму.

Ах, да: и ещё это всё нужно будет отфильтровать через условие "отличающихся друг от друга разрядом единиц", но это вы уже сами поняли. Я бы это сделал через tuple, сохранив оригинальное значение и модифицированное:

```
source.Select(x => (x, (x /10) * 10 )).Dump();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собрать итоговый ответ вы сможете самостоятельно, все компоненты я вам выдал, при сборке потренируете немного мозг в составлении "адского Linq-однострочника", а пока два небольших итоговых замечания.

Я не буду претендовать на то, что полученный результат будет самым прямым путём к исходному ответу, вполне вероятно что можно и более короткой дорогой пройти. Особенно рекомендую обратить внимание на moreLinq - библиотеку, в которой есть уже более продвинутые функции linq, возможно там будет более мощные средства.

Также хочу обратить внимание на то, что в данном случае количество постоянного итерирования исходной последовательности весьма велико - поэтому я разделяю точку зрения, что linq для данной задачи - это оверхед. Если хотите делать подобное - то только в учебных целях.

Comment: Нашёл небольшую ошибку: каждый раз в последовательности недостаёт одного элемента. например, вместо 100, 102, 104 остался огрызок 100, 102 - надо брать не Count, а Count + 1

Comment: Понял, спасибо огромное за вашу помощь.